# How to get regex backsequence in boost 1.37?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

In Ruby, when I match string like "12a" with regular expression /1(2)(a)/, I can find second and third chars in $1 and $2 variables. Like this:

```
"12a" =~ /1(2)(a)/
> $1
=> "2"
> $2
=> "a"
```

Can I make something like this in c++ Boost 1.37? 
I programming in Borland C++ 6, so last version of boost there works 1.37.0.

Comment: Those are not called "backsequences". In Ruby they are called "parenthesized groups" or "captures". If you know the correct terminology you will more easily be able to find the answers to your questions by searching.

Comment: They are called capturing group and they exist in boost's implementation too: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html

Comment: This page may help you: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/syntax.html and more precisely the "Back references" section.

Comment: Thank you guys! Its exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use library `#include <boost/regex.hpp>` for that.

See this example: [C++ Regular Expressions with Boost Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804453/c-regular-expressions-with-boost-regex)