# C++ Builder 2009 UnicodeString Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, c++builder, c++builder-2009

Curious of anyone knows of an easy, quick way to do regular expressions using `UnicodeString` in `C++ Builder 2009`.

Particularly for an IPv4 IP address.

Comment: I used the boost regex stuff shown in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804453/c-regular-expressions-with-boost-regex

Comment: @VenomFans please post it as an answer and accept it, so other people can see which is the solution

Comment: @bluish, the solution with the most up votes is what I used plus the url reference. I no longer have access to c++ builder (different job) otherwise I'd post the exact answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use DEELX Regular Expression Engine, I have written a BCB wrapper for it and downloadable from [here](http://mspay.boxhost.me/regex.h) (Independent single header).

```
char *text = "My ip is 212.122.090.180";
TMatchResult result;
TRegex <char> regex("\\b\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\b", IGNORECASE);
result = regex.Match(text, 0);
if(result.isMatched())
    printf("Found at %i-%i", result.start, result.length);
else
    printf("Not found.");
```

Comment: I ended up using the boost solution, but gave you an up vote.